# Java: Double cannot be converted to comparable

Tags: java, comparable

I have a modified quick sort method:

```
public void quickSortModified(ArrayList<Comparable> vetor, int begin, int end)
```

And I try to call it using the following code:

```
ArrayList <Double> variables = new ArrayList <Double>();
quickSortModified(variables, 0 , variables.size());
```

And Java returns me the error:

```
Incompatible types: ArrayList <Double> cannot be converted to ArrayList <Comparable>
```

If Double implements Comparable, why this code does not work?

Comment: `ArrayList<Comparable<?>>`. Although, you may find you need a type variable (so it is e.g. `public <C extends Comparable<C>> void qSM(ArrayList<C> vetor, ...)`) so that you can refer to instances in your method.

Comment: Try this: `public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quickSortModified(List<T> vector, int begin, int end)`